# Burninate [javahelp]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

[javahelp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javahelp). Why does this tag exist? It seems totally inappropriate to have a tag for language help...

Comment: Well, javahelp appears to be a website for Java help. It's understandable that asking for help with Java should be under [tag:java] instead of [tag:javahelp], but what if the asker is legitimately looking for help using the [tag:javahelp] website?

Comment: Actually, to answer my own question, that's off-topic for SO, and would be more along the lines of SuperUser anyway, since it's regarding usage of a website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to explain this. [javahelp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javahelp) is not a tag used by people asking for help in Java, it's "an online help system that developers can use to add online help to their Java platform applications." ([Source](https://javahelp.java.net/))

As such, it is a software tool used by programmers. It doesn't really matter how many questions it is, it seems to be on-topic.

Comment: Oh... Can we rename it to javahelp-system or something to avoid confusion then?

Comment: @AnubianNoob Looking through the list of questions, I only see one (closed) that was mis-tagged. I don't see it as causing a lot of confusion.